# Как сделать инъекцию всех имплементаций интерфейса в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Допустим, у меня имеется сервис MyService, а у него с десяток имплементаций.

Я хочу, чтобы в какой-то мой бин произошла инъекция всех существующих имплементаций интерфейса MyService в виде Set или List.

Возможно ли такое сделать стандартными средствами Spring?

Comment: Прямо так и делается :) https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injecting-collections , раздел 5

Comment: Если не секрет, то какого поведения вы хотите добиться от? Возможно, вам подойдет и первый вариант, а может стоит посмотреть в сторону фабричного метода. Пример фабрики https://www.baeldung.com/spring-framework-design-patterns

Comment: @Sergey Mitrofanov мне надо получить список хэндлеров в бине, чтобы их все закинуть в одну мапу